# Finding Cyclic Shifts Of Strings

Tags: python

I'm a beginner coder and I'm trying to find cyclic shifts of strings. A cyclic shift of a string is obtained by moving characters from the beginning of the string to the end of the string. For example, the cyclic shifts of ABCDE are: ABCDE, BCDEA, CDEAB, DEABC, EABCD. The input will consist of exactly two lines containing only uppercase letters. The first line will be
the text T, and the second line will be the string S.

Output yes if the text, T, contains a cyclic shift of the string, S. Otherwise, output no.

Sample Input:

```
ABCCDEABAA
ABCDE
```

Output for Sample Input:

```
yes
```

Comment: How is the answer to your sample input `yes`? It has to be no. The string `ABCDE` is not contained in `ABCCDEABAA` even after cyclic shifting

Comment: @DollarAkshay I think the point is that `CDEAB`, a cyclic shift of `ABCDE`, is contained in `ABCCDEABAA`.

Comment: @TomKarzes ah okay I thought I was supposed to cyclic shift `T`. But I guess the cyclic shifting only happens on `S`

Answer (score 1):

So basically you can append the string `S` to itself and lets call this string `S2`

```
s = 'ABCDE'
s2 = s + s    # s2 = 'ABCDEABCDE'
```

Since the length of the string `S` is 5, you will have to check whether `s2[i:i+5]` exists in `T` or not.

#### Code

```
t = 'ABCCDEABAA'
s = 'ABCDE'
s2 = s + s
n = len(s)

for i in range(n):
    flag = False
    if s2[i:i+n] in t:
        flag = True

    print(f"Checking for {s2[i:i+n]:s} in T = {flag}")
```

#### Output

```
Checking for ABCDE in T = False
Checking for BCDEA in T = False
Checking for CDEAB in T = True
Checking for DEABC in T = False
Checking for EABCD in T = False
```

**Time complexity** : `O(len(s)) * O(string_comparison)`